# Grpc client in .net standard fails when called from .net framework, but not .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, grpc

This is my setup:

- A: .Net Standard version=2.0 (gRPC Client library)
- B: .Net Framework version=4.8 (web application - uses the client library)
- C: .Net Core version=3.1 (WPF application - uses the client library)
- D: .Net Core version=3.1 (gRPC Server, my own creation)
- E: .Net Core Version=3 or 5 - I'm not sure. (gRPC Server, production)

**Error = "HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint."**

So... Someone else implemented this Grpc Server (E). I can call this one with both applications. No errors.

But to get a nice development environment for developing the two applications, I got the proto-file from the production server and developed my own implementation (D). I use this for testing error handling in the clients - I can control which responses the server gives.

I implemented two exactly alike unit tests, which are in fact integration tests. One in a .net framework project and one in a .net core project.

And it works for .net core test, but not the .net framework.

However, if I inject a `WinHttpHandler` instead of the `HttpClientHandler`, then it works. I really do not want to have to inject a handler (it's not even an interface).

Also the production gRPC server works, as mentioned before. But I do not know why mine fails and the production gRPC server works.

I think somehow my own implementation of the gRPC service is wrong (or lacking) but I do not know what I am missing.

Please help!

[image: Program class]

[image: Startup class]

Comment: Please post code as *text* rather than as screenshots. It's easier to read and easier to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had this in my appsetting.json (which I had copied from another project):

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
```

Of cause, deleting that from the file solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Grpc.Net.Client only works on .NET Framework (as opposed to .NET Core and .NET5+) with limitations. The reason is that .NET Framework doesn't really have a HTTP/2 implementation, which is a requirement for gRPC protocol (but not for grpc-web, it that's an option for you).

Grpc.Net.Client works on .NET Framework to some extent with WinHttpHandler (as you've discovered). The limitations are documented here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-grpc-client-requirements
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-framework

Comment: Thank you. My problem was solved by fixing an overeager copy-and-paste from another project. I had in fact accidentally told Kestrel to use Http2. Duh!